# Computing the total energy of Nonlinear Schrödinger (NLS) equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dispersive-pde

NLS:

> $$ i\, u_t + \frac 12 u_{xx} \pm \lVert u\rVert^2u=0 $$
>
> Show that the following energy of the nonlinear Schrödinger (NLS) equation is constant
>   $$
> E=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \left(
> \frac 12 \lVert u_x \rVert^2\mp \frac 12 \lVert u \rVert^4
> \right) \, dx = \mbox{const} 
> $$

I don't know how I can show this.

Comment: Formally? Try to differentiate w.r.t $t$ and use your equation. Of course you should justify your differentiation under the integral sign...

Comment: My guess: Bring the equation into the form $i \partial_t u = H u$ and calculate the expectation value of the energy operator $H$ for some solution $u$, which is then replaced by the $i \partial_t$.

Comment: An equation has no energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of a non-rigorous answer, which I suspect is all you want.

Your equation is of the form $i u_t = Hu$.  Multiply it by $\bar u_t$ to get $i \|u_t\|^2 = \bar u_t Hu$.  Now take the real part this to get
$$ 0 = \bar u_t Hu + u_t H \bar{u_t} .$$
Now integrate both sides with respect to $x$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  You will have to do an integration by parts to show
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar u_t u_{xx} \, dx = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar u_{tx} u_{x} \, dx $$
and another equality which is simply the complex conjugate of this.  (You will need to suppose that $u \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ to delete the cross terms.)  Then use formulas like
$$ \partial_t \|u_{x}\|^2 = \bar u_{xt} u_x + u_{xt} \bar u_x .$$
Then pull the derivatives outside of the integrals.

Making it all rigorous is quite a bit harder, and involves Hilbert spaces and Sobolev spaces, etc.